# How to open Facebook Messenger and direct to someone?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have FBSDK already and can use FBSDKShareKit send something on Messenger.
I want just open a chat with someone in Facebook Messenger. like this:

1. Click a button in my app(sample: Facebook app):
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/9blQk.jpg
2. Go to Facebook Messenger and open a chat with this person:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9OQT.png

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 4

### UI

In my app I show a user's Facebook ID as a button:
[image: FB ID]

### Code

```
@IBAction func messengerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let id = sender.titleLabel?.text {
        if let url = URL(string: "fb-messenger://user-thread/\(id)") {

            // Attempt to open in Messenger App first
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
                (success) in

                if success == false {
                    // Messenger is not installed. Open in browser instead.
                    let url = URL(string: "https://m.me/\(id)")
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

### User's Facebook ID

The user can get another person's Facebook ID from looking them up on Facebook and then observing the URL:

[image: FB ID from URL]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with URL Scheme:

```
let userID = 4
let urlStr = String(format: "fb-messenger://user-thread/%d", userID)
let theUrl = NSURL(string: urlStr)
[UIApplication.sharedApplication() .openURL(theUrl!)]
```

This code will open Message application and talk to Mark.

Answer (score 0):

in swift 5.1, use

```
     guard let messenger = URL(string: "fb-messenger://user-thread/your_id") else { return }
 UIApplication.shared.open(messenger)
```