# Facebook graph API link parameter returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I am trying to store a logged in facebook user's facebook username (eg www.facebook.com/**james.dean01**) in order to connect people via messenger (similar to [How to open Facebook Messenger and direct to someone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542659/how-to-open-facebook-messenger-and-direct-to-someone)). I am configuring a button which will send a user directly to someones messenger chat but to do so I need their username/facebook URL. I am attempting to use the "link" property (Facebook graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) to obtain a link to the user's profile which could be used for this purpose, only the link property (printed) returns nil. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The aim is that each time a user logs in the data is read and the database is updated. Below is the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import FacebookCore

class FacebookService {
static let instance = FacebookService()

let params = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, link, picture, name"]

func recordUserData() {
    let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.start {
        (urlResponse, requestResult) in

        switch requestResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print("error in graph request:", error)
            break
        case .success(let graphResponse):
            if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                print(responseDictionary)

                let link = responseDictionary["link"] as? String
                let email = responseDictionary["email"] as? String
                let fbId = responseDictionary["id"] as? String
                let name = responseDictionary["name"] as? String

                let picture = responseDictionary["picture"] as? NSDictionary
                let data = picture!["data"] as? NSDictionary
                let url = data!["url"] as? String

                print("Link: \(link)")
                print(url)

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask for the necessary permission? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link But I doubt you would get this through review anyway, because what you would be doing is essentially what it says there is a not allowed use case: _“Attempt to programmatically determine someone's Facebook username or canonical User ID.”_

Comment: aaaah I see, so I need to get my app reviewed in order for me to have access to the link to their facebook page? @misorude

Comment: Yes, the use of most permissions and some extended features require review by Facebook, before you can use them in your live app.

Comment: thanks bro, if you post an answer I'll just mark it as the solution or whatever people do on here :) @misorude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask for the necessary permission, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link

And the use of this permission requires review by Facebook, before you can use it in your live app.

Not sure you would get this through review though, because what you would be doing is essentially what it says there is a not allowed use case:

> Attempt to programmatically determine someone's Facebook username or canonical User ID.

So no guarantee Facebook will approve this; you can only try and submit it for review and see what feedback you get.